# When with is called for a data frame, how can we refer to the parent data frame without using its name?

Tags: r, environment

Consider `with(mtcars, split(mtcars,cyl == 8 & disp > 350))`. When writing complex code, particularly anything more complex than this example, `with` lets us significantly cut down on the number of times that we need to write `mtcars`. However, even in this simple example, I had to write `mtcars` twice. Is there any way around this when using `with`? Perhaps something similar to `Recall()`? What I want is some way to say `with(data, foo(dataFrameThatMadeThisEnvironment(),partOfData))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such function in base R. `with` is basically just a convenience wrapper for interactive use. You could fairly trivially write your own

```
withself <- function(data, expr) {
  env <- new.env(parent = parent.frame())
  env$self <- function() data
  eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = env)
}
withself(mtcars, split(self(),cyl == 8 & disp > 350))
```

Of you could "hack" the `with` call stack. For example

```
withdata <- function() parent.frame(3)$data
with(mtcars, split(withdata(),cyl == 8 & disp > 350))
```

but it's really not meant to be used like that.

In the `tidyverse` world you avoid repitition with pipes

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl == 8 & disp > 350) %>% 
  group_split()
```

Or just using the `matrittr::%>%` pipe operator

```
mtcars %>% with(., split(., cyl == 8 & disp > 350))
```

I don't believe the upcoming native R pipe operator will allow you to pass the same value multiple times, but I guess we will have to see what the final version will do.